# Export excel files without VBA buttons

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file that I need to export without the VBA buttons. Every time I export it as a Xlsm file, the macros and button export too.

I want to export the excel file as my final report. However, every time I export it, buttons and macros export too.

Comment: You can delete the buttons with code, and save as xlsx to remove the macros.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're exporting to PDF here as @TimWilliams has the "Export as Excel file" route covered.
If I I try to export this report:

[image]

You can see it still keeps my export button.

---

If I set the button to "Do Not print":

[image]
[image]

Then when I try to export:

[image]

Button is not included in export.

Comment: That didn’t work, I want to save it as .xlsx but without the macro buttons on the spreadsheet

Comment: I submitted a second answer with how to remove all (or some) shapes before export

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all control buttons on your report before deleting, you can use the following Sub:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Main()
    
    ' Example Sub to demonstrate usage

    Dim ReportWS As Worksheet
    Dim ShapeToKeep As String
    
    Set ReportWS = Worksheets("Report")
    ShapeToKeep = "Ctrl2"
    
    DeleteControls ReportWS, ShapeToKeep

    'Export Workbook
    
End Sub
Sub DeleteControls(WS As Worksheet, Optional Keep As String)
    
    ' Delete all shapes (except excluded) on sheet 

    Dim Shp As Shape
    
    For Each Shp In WS.Shapes
        If Not IsMissing(Keep) Then
            If Shp.Name <> Keep Then
                Shp.Delete
            End If
        Else
            Shp.Delete
        End If
    Next Shp
    
End Sub
```

This includes the option to keep specific Shape by name.
If you want to exclude multiple shapes, change Keep to a dictionary.
This is specific to "Shapes", you could change it to delete other objects.

Example:

**Before:**
[image]

**After:** (with optional excluded shape)
[image]

**After:** (no excluded shape)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I ended using the following code and it worked.

Sub DeleteAllShapes()

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.SelectAll

Selection.Delete
```

save_name = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Excel File (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=save_name, FileFormat:=51
End Sub